# CMake FetchContent downloads external dependencies multiple times

Tags: android, cmake

I started to use FetchContent for automatical download of external dependencies. It works nicely compared to older approaches but I have one problem which is probably not related to FetchContent itself - external dependencies are downloaded multiple times. I'm actually building for Android platform but that doesn't matter much.
I call CMake like this `cmake -B build/arm64-v8a ...` or `cmake -B build/x86 ...`. I need separate build folders for each ABI (arm64-v8a, x86, ...) to avoid rebuilds because I switch between ABIs frequently.
But when I use simple FetchContent constructions like:

```
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/googletest.git
  GIT_TAG        release-1.8.0
)

FetchContent_GetProperties(googletest)
if(NOT googletest_POPULATED)
  FetchContent_Populate(googletest)
  add_subdirectory(${googletest_SOURCE_DIR} ${googletest_BINARY_DIR})
endif()
```

it will download external project once per ABI (in other words - once per CMake call using different build folder), because `googletest_POPULATED` is not visible in next CMake call using different build folder. It would be awesome if sources would be downloaded once.

So I tried passing `SOURCE_DIR` in `FetchContent_Declare` to save source one level up (in `build/_deps/googletest-src` not `build/<abi>/_deps/googletest-src` folder). It saved sources correctly but re-download was still triggered as it seems that `googletest-subbuild` folder (located under `build/<abi>/_deps`) manages `googletest_POPULATED` flag.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using `FETCHCONTENT_BASE_DIR` to share the CMake project that is created that handles downloading management.  Then make sure to use separate build directories for building the software.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(fc_twice)

include (FetchContent)
set(FETCHCONTENT_QUIET off)
get_filename_component(fc_base "../fc_base"
                       REALPATH BASE_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")
set(FETCHCONTENT_BASE_DIR ${fc_base})

FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/googletest.git
  GIT_TAG        release-1.8.0
)

FetchContent_GetProperties(googletest)
if(NOT googletest_POPULATED)
  FetchContent_Populate(googletest)
  #create gt build directory in binary tree
  add_subdirectory(${googletest_SOURCE_DIR} gt)
endif()
```

When switching between build directories some bookkeeping items are repeated but the actual download will only occur once.  You should see the message:

```
  Performing download step (git clone) for 'googletest-populate'
  -- Avoiding repeated git clone, stamp file is up to date: 'C:/Users/XXX/Desktop/temp/so_fc/fc_base/googletest-subbuild/googletest-populate-prefix/src/googletest-populate-stamp/googletest-populate-gitclone-lastrun.txt'
```

I tested using the commands `cmake -S src/ -B bld1` and `cmake -S src/ -B bld2` and switched back and for building them.

Comment: Thanks, this really works! Minor imperfection in this solution is that CMake has to re-generate subbuild folder (you mentioned bookkeeping) for every external dependency but it's acceptable for me.

Comment: @jozols I took another look.  It was being regenerated because `fc_base` was a relative path from the build directory (which keeps changing).  If you use some sort of absolute path then that doesn't happen.  I updated the example to determine the directory that contains `bld1` and `bld2` and use it as an absolute path.  Then `CMakeLists.txt` in `subbuild` remains the same and nothing is re-generated.

Comment: @fdk1342 I tested this, and it works for a single configuration, but fails when I switch to another configuration. For example, if I swap between a 32 and 64 bit build, CMake complains that there is a mismatch between the cached generator platform (Win32) and the new one (x64)