# Cmake FetchContent have source and binary in different directories?

Tags: c++, cmake

I want to reuse the source folder of my external libraries declared by *FetchContent* to avoid multiple downloads for multiple build configurations (debug/release/android/emscripten). To clarify, the build configurations have different binary directories e.g. /build/debug, build/release...
The ideal solution would be to have the source of the external depenendency in *{CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ext* and the binary dir in *{CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${name}-build*

When using *FETCHCONTENT_BASE_DIR* (see example below) the source directory gets shared but also the binary directory, which triggers a complete rebuild whenever I switch between build configurations.

There is also the *BINARY_DIR* parameter for *FetchContent_Populate*, but it seems not do give the desired results.

```
set(FETCHCONTENT_BASE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/depenendencies)
FetchContent_Declare(
  ${name}
  GIT_REPOSITORY ${url}
  GIT_TAG ${tag}
  GIT_PROGRESS ON
)

FetchContent_GetProperties(${name})
if (NOT ${name}_POPULATED)
  FetchContent_Populate(
  ${name}
)
add_subdirectory(${${name}_SOURCE_DIR} ${${name}_BINARY_DIR})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMake FetchContent downloads external dependencies multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56329088/cmake-fetchcontent-downloads-external-dependencies-multiple-times)

Comment: Have you tried setting `SOURCE_DIR` in addition to `BINARY_DIR` (and also `SOURCE_DUBDIR` if relevant) in the `FetchContent_Declare` arguments? Thoes get passed to `ExternalProject_Add`.

Answer (score 0):

No good solution out of the box, but I tried the following:

```
include(FetchContent)
set(FETCH_TARGET_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/fetched
    CACHE STRING "Target directory for fetching sources by FetchContent")
 
function(FetchContent_DeclareEx contentName)
    FetchContent_Declare(${ARGV} SOURCE_DIR ${FETCH_TARGET_DIR}/${contentName})
endfunction()
```

It introduces the CMake cache variable `FETCH_TARGET_DIR` for the destination directory of the sources to fetch. By default, the sources are placed in `fetched` subdirectory of the CMake root project. (Add it to `.gitignore`.)

Then declaring the dependencies is done via the `FetchContent_DeclareEx` with the usual arguments. This function defines `SOURCE_DIR` option for `FetchContent_Declare` according to `FETCH_TARGET_DIR`.

This of course works only if you can replace all `FetchContent_Declare` calls with `FetchContent_DeclareEx` which is not always possible...